# How to cycle through visual-regexp package findings?

Tags: search

With the regular search forward from Emacs if you keep pressing `C-s` you cycle through all the findings.

Right now I'm using [visual-regexp package](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el) with the [visual-regexp-steroids extension](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/) that has a forward search too, but using regular expressions ( `vr/isearch-forward`). After running the search how do I cycle through all the findings?.

Comment: What is "visual regex package"? Just what are you doing to install and initiate it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I should clarify more the question. I just updated the question with more info.

Comment: I see no `vr/isearch-forward` in [visual-regexp package](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el). So far, the question risks being closed as unclear.

Comment: Is in a extension of that package [visual-regexp-steroids](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've clarified that you use `vr/isearch-forward` from `visual-regexp-steroids.el`, I tried it, and I see no problem. Repeating `C-s` advances through the search hits.

IOW, it works for me, at least.  All I did was load the file, set `vr/engine` to `emacs` (since I am used to Emacs-style regexps), and try `vr/isearch-forward` with a simple regexp. Using `C-s` repeatedly after that navigated through the search hits.

Does it not work if you start Emacs without your init file: `emacs -Q`? If that works then recursively bisect your init file to find out what causes the problem.

Comment: Ok,then if it works on yours, it's a problem with my configuration or my  Emacs. I'll test getting rid of everything but the essential for the visual search to work and see if it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Author of the package here. Hitting `C-s` and `C-r` should work. Just tested it with the python engine.

Comment: It does work, the problem was that I mapped the C-s to your package, so when I pressed the second time the C-s it didn't cycle through the findings.

Comment: Also, thank you for that awesome work you did, I really appreciate the tool.